# echo an element of an array in php/json

Tags: php, arrays, json

array:

```
["author"]=> array(1) { 
    [0] => array(2) { 
        ["name"]=> array(1) {
            ["$t"]=> string(10) "CALLOFDUTY" 
        }}}
```

my code (not working) :

```
$entry["author"]["0"]["name"]["$t"]
```

Do you find any errors in the php code above ?
whats wrong ? :S

Comment: I took the liberty of better formatting your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is a special character inside double quotes, if you want to use it as a character you need to escape it: `\$`, or use single quotes instead.

As it is your code is looking for an array element with an index whose value is in a variable called `$t`

Answer (score 3):

You should use single quotation marks to circumvent problems. Also, you should make sure you use the correct key type - integer 0 is not the same as a character "0".

```
$entry['author'][0]['name']['$t']
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$entry["author"][0]["name"]['$t']
```